# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined goormIDE

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, seed

I keep getting this error and my server wouldn't run.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
> at /workspace/YelpCamp/v3/seeds.js:73:26
> at /workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
> at Function. (/workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4905:21)
> at _done (/workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3109:12)
> at fn (/workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3118:18)
> at callbackWrapper (/workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3074:11)
> at /workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4882:16
> at /workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
> at /workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4905:21
> at model.$__save.error (/workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:496:7)
> at /workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/kareem/index.js:315:21
> at next (/workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/kareem/index.js:209:27)
> at /workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/kareem/index.js:182:9
> at process.nextTick (/workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/kareem/index.js:507:38)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11) Emitted 'error' event at:
> at /workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4884:13
> at /workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
> at /workspace/YelpCamp/v3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4905:21
> [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

My code:

```js
function seedDB() {
//Remove all campgrounds
Campground.deleteMany({}, function(err){
if(err){
    console.log(err);
}
console.log("removed campground!");
//add a few campgrounds
seeds.forEach(function(seed) {
    Campground.create(seed, function(err, campground){
        if(err){
            console.log("ERR IN CREATE")
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("added a campground");
            //add a few comments
            Comment.create(
            {
                text: "This place is great!",
                author: "Homer"
            }, function(err, comment){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                campground.comments.push(comment);
                campground.save();
                console.log("Created new comments");
                }   
            });
          }
       })
     });
  });       
 }
```

Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: Insufficient Information

Comment: Does the  `Campground` schema has a property `comments` of type array